# BeautifulSoup finding html tags only (no class)

Tags: python, html

Hey guys I am currently learning Python (in PyCharm) and I have been following some Tutorials

and have this working code:

```
        import requests
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        import operator


        def start(url):
            word_list = []
            source_code = requests.get(url).text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code)
            for post_text in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'index_singleListingTitles'}):
                content = post_text.string
                words = content.lower().split() #make all lower case and splits it up (based on spaces)
                for each_word in words:
                    print(each_word)
                    word_list.append(each_word)

        start('https://www.thenewboston.com/tops.php?type=text&period=this-month')
```

But the code I am foucesed on is: `for post_text in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'index_singleListingTitles'}):` it uses BeautifulSoup to sort the html source of a webpage for tags, class etc.. and get the info

I can't seem to set it to find `Strong` tags for the below:

```
<a href="/anime/5114/Fullmetal_Alchemist:_Brotherhood" class="hoverinfo_trigger" id="#area5114" rel="#info5114"><strong>Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood</strong></a>
```

I know most web pages have tos against scrapping them (I am only doing this to try other sites and one page only, I am not making any programs or anything harmful) just learning.

I have tried a lot of things, I am starting to thing it doesn't work on the web page I'm trying it on but I doubt BeautifulSoup is possible to to block..

Any help would be great, have only been learning python for 2 days so go easy on me! thanks.

Comment: The page you are sourcing does not have any "strong" tags. Create a local html page for your testing with the required tags and then play on top of that.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't using that page I gave an example of my "working" code and then a snippet of the code from another site and page. Thought it was clear, haven't added the other site because of permission reasons only the snippet of needed code from other site.

Comment: Can you create a sample page and post it on gist? Coz the exact solution will differ as per the content of the page.